# WebStorm 2018.3: project tool window colours?

Tags: colors, ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to configure the foreground/background colours of the WebStorm Project Tool Window? I have been unable to find the settings.

Answer (score 1):

No, as it's defined in UI theme. UI themes (used for dialogs, tool windows, etc.) are Java Look&Feels. This is a standard way to style Swing applications. As such, they are hardcoded and can't be changed easily.

Note that it's technically possible to install any third-party L&F into JVM and use it in WebStorm ( see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html, https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kirillcool/archive/2005/08/intellij_idea_5.html for instructions). Custom themes can also be implemented as plugins, like [Material UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui) and [Afterglow Theme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8066-afterglow-theme) - you can give them a try.

Note that we’re working on a feature allowing themes customization in IntelliJ Platform. Please follow [IDEA-132299](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132299) to get updates.